# Making 2 horizontal buttons fill modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

I wanna make my horizontal buttons fill my modal view.

This is what I made, using this button classes: [click here](http://bootsnipp.com/snippets/featured/buttons-with-labels)

**HTML:**

```
<div class="modal fade" id="usuario_info" abindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myInfoUser" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-body">
                <center>
                    <img src="https://encrypted-tbn2.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcRbezqZpEuwGSvitKy3wrwnth5kysKdRqBW54cAszm_wiutku3R" name="aboutme" width="96" height="96" border="0" class="img-circle">
                    <h3 class="media-heading" id="bookId"></h3>
                </center>
                <br>
                <div class="panel panel-primary">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <h3 class="panel-title">Subtitle</h3>
                    </div>
                    <p class="cuerpo-info-user">Something</p>
                </div>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-phone"></i></span>
                    Call him      

                </button>
                <button type="button button-infousuario" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="fa fa-ban"></i></span>
                    More information
                </button>
                <button type="button button-infousuario" class="btn btn-labeled btn-success">
                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="icon_check"></i></span>
                    Success
                </button>
                <button type="button button-infousuario" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger">
                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="icon-cancel"></i></span>
                    Remove him
                </button>
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-labeled btn-danger button-infousuario">
                    <span class="btn-label"><i class="icon-trash"></i></span>
                    Remove everything
                </button>
            </dsiv>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- End modal -->
```

**My result:**

[image]

I tried with:

```
.button-infousuario{
    display:inline-block;
}
```

but not working.

Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood you correctly, you can make your buttons fill your modal view by setting their `width: 100%`. But the text will appear in the center of the button. To prevent that you can set `text-align: left`

```
.button-infousuario{
   width: 100%;
   text-align: left;
}
```